# Hibernate HQL to SQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

Given the following entity one-to-many model:

One Repository can be linked to many AuditRecords.

Many AuditRecords can all link to the same Repository

```
@Entity
class AuditRecordEntity {
  private AuditRepositoryEntity auditRepository;  

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = AUDIT_REPOSITORY_DB_COLUMN_NAME, nullable = false, updatable = false)
  public AuditRepositoryEntity getAuditRepository() {
    return auditRepository;
  }
  ...
}

@Entity
class AuditRepositoryEntity {
  private List<AuditRecordEntity> auditRecords = new ArrayList<AuditRecordEntity>();

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "auditRepository")
  public List<AuditRecordEntity> getAuditRecords() {
    return auditRecords;
  }
  ...
}
```

I have the following HQL query to get the latest (by accessTime) AuditRecord for each distinct Repository:

```
select auditRecord from AuditRecordEntity auditRecord where auditRecord.accessTime = 
(select max(auditRecord2.accessTime) from AuditRecordEntity auditRecord2 where  
auditRecord2.auditRepository = auditRecord.auditRepository)
```

I would like to know the equivalent SQL for the above HQL?

(the reason for this is I'l like to add the query as an sql restriction using the criteria API, as I am having trouble translating the HQL above to use the criteria API - see [Hibernate criteria implementation for this entity model (subquery, self-join)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919038/hibernate-criteria-implementation-for-this-entity-model-subquery-self-join))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one hibernate property named

```
hibernate.show_sql
```

You can set it true in your hibernate configuration file or property file. It will show you the equivalent sql query of your hql/criteria query.